# XSLT Encoding Issue

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8, saxon

I have the following XML:

```
<item>
    <description><![CDATA[Euro sign: €]]></description>
</item>
```

When I run it against this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">

    <xsl:output method="xml" name="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:result-document href="test.xml" format="xml">        
            <feed>
                <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </feed>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the "test.xml" is equal to:

```
<feed>
    <description>Euro sign: €</description>
</feed>
```

which is perfect. However, when the `<xsl:result-document>` is removed, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">

    <xsl:output method="xml" name="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <feed>
            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </feed>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output equals:

```
<feed>
    <description>Euro sign: â‚¬</description>
</feed>
```

which is incorrect as the euro sign has been escaped it seems.

Is there any way to keep the euro sign as is when using plain output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you viewing the output? To me it looks like you get the right UTF-8 result, but you seem to be viewing it in an user agent (console window?, browser?) that does not interpret UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: I agree with mzjn. And I would suggest simply to change the `xsl:output` directive to say `omit-xml-declaration="no"`, that way the XML document created will start with an XML declaration telling the XML editor or viewer which encoding is used and the rendering should work.

Comment: I also agree. I find it useful to use XML character entities wherever possible - there are many places in current toolchains where encodings may get corrupted. And always declare the encoding in the xml-declaration (I always try to use UTF-8 if possible)

Comment: Thanks guys! Yep, you're right. We were displaying the data in the Console window of Eclipse, which wasn't setup for UTF-8. Once we altered the settings of the console to output in UTF-8, the output was fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: If you've resolved your question, you can add the resolution as an answer and accept it so that people know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were displaying the data in the Console window of Eclipse, which wasn't setup for UTF-8. Once we altered the settings of the console to output in UTF-8, the output was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the name attribute from your xsl:output element:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

By making it an unnamed xsl:output element it should apply to the current run.

Comment: Thanks! We were able to fix it by changing the output encoding of the console window. Answer now added.